# Cannot see mySQL COUNT from 3rd table

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have posted another message like this.  But none helped.  So I have done some more reading and I have this code which works to a point:

**EDIT NEW VERSION & NEW ISSUE**

```
SELECT i.*, o.organ_name, o.organ_logo, vtable.*
FROM heroku_056eb661631f253.op_ideas i
JOIN
(SELECT
    COUNT(v.agree) as agree,
    COUNT(v.disagree = 1 or null) as disagree,
    COUNT(v.obstain = 1 or null) as abstain
FROM op_idea_vote v
) AS vtable
LEFT JOIN op_organs o ON i.post_type = o.organs_id
```

There is only 1 row in the op_idea_vote table, and 3 in the op_ideas table.  But it's giving each row the total in each op_ideas row

**EDIT WORKING SOLUTION**

Thanks to WayneC, here is the working code:

```
SELECT i.*, o.organ_name, o.organ_logo, vtable.*
FROM heroku_056eb661631f253.op_ideas i
JOIN
   (SELECT v.idea_Id,
    COUNT(v.agree = 1 or null) as agree,
    COUNT(v.disagree = 1 or null) as disagree,
    COUNT(v.obstain = 1 or null) as abstain
   FROM op_idea_vote v
   GROUP BY v.idea_id
   ) AS vtable ON vtable.idea_id = i.idea_id
LEFT JOIN op_organs o ON i.post_type = o.organs_id
WHERE idea_geo = 'International';
```

Comment: you didn't select them in the main query

Comment: When i try and put them in the main query, I do not get a result.  As it's a different table, I read mySQL doc as it would do a sperate query on that table and bolt it onto the end of the main query result ?

Comment: all your query will ever return is `i.*, o.organ_name, o.organ_logo` - that's it.  It doesn't matter how many subqueries you make or how many joins you make, nothing will be magically appended to the results.

Comment: Thanks Sam.  Does this mean what I am trying is not possible in one query statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT i.*, o.organ_name, o.organ_logo, vtable.*
FROM heroku_056eb661631f253.op_ideas i
JOIN
    (SELECT
        COUNT(v.agree) as agree,
        COUNT(v.disagree = 1 or null) as disagree,
        COUNT(v.obstain = 1 or null) as abstain
    FROM op_idea_vote v
    GROUP BY v.idea_id
    ) AS vtable ON vtable.idea_id = i.idea_id
LEFT JOIN op_organs o ON i.post_type = o.organs_id
```

The answer below was missing the group by, and join condition for vtable

Comment: You are officially my best friend!!  Thank you.

Comment: I have posted a new example.  Not sure what I am doing wrong, but i tried to add another select to count the number of comments per idea.  Could check where i am going wrong.  Syntax is right as it's the same as the one you did, but i am getting no results.  So must be where I have placed it?

Comment: You should probably add that as a new question, so this question still makes sense

Comment: Here you are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900307/two-subqueries-added-to-addition-complex-mysql-query-returning-no-records

Answer (score 1):

Here's your original query

```
SELECT i.*, o.organ_name, o.organ_logo
FROM heroku_056eb661631f253.op_ideas i
JOIN
    (SELECT
        COUNT(v.agree) as agree,
        COUNT(v.disagree = 1 or null) as disagree,
        COUNT(v.obstain = 1 or null) as abstain
    FROM op_idea_vote v, op_ideas i
    WHERE v.idea_id = i.idea_id
    ) AS vtable
  LEFT JOIN op_organs o ON i.post_type = o.organs_id
```

`vtable` is a subquery masquerading as a table you're joining to - in terms of getting the fields to be returned with the query results, it's no different from joining a normal table.  You have to select the fields you want returned in the main query, or they won't be returned.

```
SELECT i.*, o.organ_name, o.organ_logo, vtable.*
FROM heroku_056eb661631f253.op_ideas i
JOIN
    (SELECT
        COUNT(v.agree) as agree,
        COUNT(v.disagree = 1 or null) as disagree,
        COUNT(v.obstain = 1 or null) as abstain
    FROM op_idea_vote v, op_ideas i
    WHERE v.idea_id = i.idea_id
    ) AS vtable
  LEFT JOIN op_organs o ON i.post_type = o.organs_id
```

Comment: That looks great Sam. I see what I did wrong by not adding the table. However there is currently only one vote out of the three row in the agree.  But the result shows a 1 in each row.  Can I pass a i.idea_id into the subquery ?  At the moment, that code is not passing through the query as it should ?

Comment: I tried adding: `@id:=i.idea_id` in the top SELECT and in the subquery I added `WHERE v.idea_id = @id`   Still no joy though ?

Comment: It feels like the query maybe inside out, does that make sense ?