# PHP while loop within a while loop works once

Tags: php, mysql

I have two queries sent to a database bring back posts (op_ideas 16 cols) followed by another which holds the votes per post (op_idea_vote cols 4) with matching idea_id's

Example of Data:

Query: op_ideas:

> [{"idea_id":"2211","author_id":"100000", "date":"2012-09-06
>   10:02:28","idea_title":"Another test","4" etc etc

Query: op_idea_votes:

> idea_id = 2211, agree=3, disagree=1, abstain=0

The code below ought to look at op_ideas, and then cycle over op_ideas_vote until it finds a match under 'idea_id'.  Then it goes to the next record under op_ideas, and again using that idea_id search for it within the op_idea_vote list, find a match, and add it to the array.

This works for only the first record, not for the other three.  I am testing, so I have 3 rows in each that match idea_id with different results in the op_idea_vote.

```
$votes = mysql_query($commentVotes);

$result = mysql_query($gl_query);

while ($gce_result = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $voteid = $gce_result['idea_id'];

    while($allvotes= mysql_fetch_array($votes)) {
        if($voteid = $allvotes['idea_id']) 
        {
        //echo $voteid . " main idea and the votes: " . $allvotes;
            $gce_result["agree"] = $allvotes['agree'];
            $gce_result["disagree"] = $allvotes['disagree'];
            $gce_result["abstain"] = $allvotes['obstain'];
        } 
        else 
        {
            $gce_result["agree"] = 0;
            $gce_result["disagree"] = 0;
            $gce_result["abstain"] = 0;
        }
        //print_r($gce_result);
    }
    $data_result[] = $gce_result;
}

echo json_encode($data_result);
```

If I use `print_f(&gce_result)` it works fine in phpfiddle.  But when i use the code above, it works for the first record, but it's complete missing the second two.  It seems to be missing the second while, as it does not even give me the 0 0 0 results.

**Query for op_ideas:**

```
$gl_query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM heroku_056eb661631f253.op_ideas INNER JOIN op_organs ORDER BY date ASC;";
if (!mysql_query($gl_query)) {
    die('Error: ' . $gl_query . " " . mysql_error());
}
$result = mysql_query($gl_query);
```

**Query For op_idea_vote :**

```
$commentVotes = "SELECT v.idea_id, COUNT(v.agree = 1 or null) as agree, COUNT(v.disagree =   1 or null) as disagree, COUNT(v.obstain = 1 or null) as obstain FROM op_idea_vote v GROUP BY  v.idea_id";
if (!mysql_query($commentVotes)) {
    die('Error: ' . $commentVotes . " " . mysql_error());
}
$votes = mysql_query($commentVotes);
```

Comment: Can you show the queries? Might be easier to do this with a join

Comment: Are you really intending to perform a cross join between `op_ideas` and `op_organs`?  Despite `INNER JOIN` keywords, you've not provided a join condition (so this actually performs a `CROSS JOIN` in MySQL).

Comment: @eggyal I tried the SQL query yesterday, with no prival. I could not make it work and I put up two different types of code on here, but nobody could help.  So instead I have done two queries, and added them server side.  This works, other than the While stops after the first iteration.  I tired `mysql_data_seek($votes, 0)` but that did not work, only copied the first result.   Something is stopping the second while, as it does not even get to the second `IF` statement after the first row.

Comment: Firstly, it's worth noting that sometimes questions take more than a day to be answered here.  I have open questions from over a month ago, to which I am still hoping to receive an answer.  Secondly, if "*nobody could help*" it's likely that your question was unclear or difficult to understand: work on clarifying your requirements in those previous questions and you may well get a prompt and helpful answer.  Thirdly, it's *extremely* unclear from this question exactly what it is that you're trying to accomplish and there's almost certainly a **much** better way than what you're doing.

Comment: If you can avoid it, please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql` functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Comment: @eggyal Thank you for the response.  I have two queries and I am wanting to merge the results based on the equal of `idea_id`.  Once if finds a match, the result is added to the object. Then it starts over again.  Works the first time, but the rest of the results from `$gce_query` jumps the second `While`.
As for making sense, people interpretate information differently, so I can only do my best until people ask for more information on a particular part of code.  I am unable to assume what people may need to know.  Once asked, I am prompt in supplying the info.

Comment: `$gce_result["abstain"] = $allvotes['obstain'];` This segment of your code looks suspicious. I thought you said your query for _op_idea_votes_ returns: `idea_id = 2211, agree=3, disagree=1, abstain=0`. What happens if you change `obstain` to `abstain`?

Answer (score 1):

You can scan a resource only once.
So the inner while will be run only one time.

Answer (score 0):

use `==` instead of `=` for checking condition of `if` & `while`
in the while loop ,you have to assign the value of $allvotes ,but you never assigned,

```
while ($gce_result == mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $voteid = $gce_result['idea_id'];

    while($allvotes== mysql_fetch_array($votes)) {
        if($voteid == $allvotes['idea_id']) 
        {
        //echo $voteid . " main idea and the votes: " . $allvotes;
            $gce_result["agree"] = $allvotes['agree'];
            $gce_result["disagree"] = $allvotes['disagree'];
            $gce_result["abstain"] = $allvotes['obstain'];
        } 
        else 
        {
            $gce_result["agree"] = 0;
            $gce_result["disagree"] = 0;
            $gce_result["abstain"] = 0;
        }
        $data_result[] = $gce_result;
    }

}
```

Comment: how can that work, $allvotes wont get assigned the result of the mysql_fetch, so the rest of the code becomes pointless, same with $gce_result

Comment: If I use == on the while, I get no results at all?  And on the IF it still did not correct the problem?

Comment: @AndrewWalker: yes ,if your $allvotes not equal to return value of mysql_fetch_array($result)

Comment: What he was doing is a common pattern for looping over mysql results. The while loop is not checking if $allvotes its equal, it just needs to know that it is "truthy", Ie, mysql_fetch_array is returning a new row, if it is false, there are no more rows to fetch

Comment: @Ravindrabagale They are different results.  $result brings back all the posts and $allvotes ($votes) only brings back votes.  If I use == on the first 'while' it does not give any results, so it cannot get to the second while.  That what I mean.

Comment: @AndrewWalker: if you are using while loop for assigning value,then this not requirement of while loop

Comment: What does that mean, @Ravindrabagale, how would you loop over a mysql_query?

Comment: @WayneC:   while returns boolean value,it is used for checking the condition,& it executes code until it satisfying condition

Comment: @WayneC: for looping mysql_query you have to check condition

Comment: You are completely on the wrong track, his while code is correct. It assigns the result of mysql_fetch_array to $allvotes, and then checks the boolean value of that. The problem is trying to loop over the $votes resource more than once

Comment: Seriously this method of usign a while loop to iterate over a result is in the php manual http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php. Admittedly he should be using something other than mysql_* functions, but the pattern is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is trying to scan over the $votes result more than once.

You should store the result of that query first.

Eg.

```
while ($vote = mysql_fetch_array($votes)) {
    $allvotes['idea_id'] = $vote;
}

while ($gce_result = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $voteid = $gce_result['idea_id'];
    if (array_key_exists[$voteid, $allvotes]) {
       //assign results
    } else {
       //default
    }
}
```

Another option would be to do the query with a join, so you can do everything in one query. Then just loop over that result.

Comment: Thank you.  I have tried the SQL approach here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874647/cannot-see-mysql-count-from-3rd-table/12874827#12874827[link]   I will try your suggestion and get back in a mo

Comment: Go with the sql one if you can.