# Two subqueries added to addition complex mySQL query returning no records

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I have this code, and individually they all work, so I think it must be the syntax which is incorrectly placed:

```
SELECT i.*, o.organ_name, o.organ_logo, vtable.*, cc.ccount
FROM heroku_056eb661631f253.op_ideas i
JOIN
```

The above collects all records from op_ideas table.

```
(SELECT v.idea_Id,
    COUNT(v.agree = 1 or null) as agree,
    COUNT(v.disagree = 1 or null) as disagree,
    COUNT(v.obstain = 1 or null) as abstain
FROM op_idea_vote v
GROUP BY v.idea_id
) AS vtable ON vtable.idea_id = i.idea_id
```

The above then searches another table and counts the votes for each record and adds it to the row.

```
JOIN 
(SELECT ccc.idea_id AS cid, COUNT(ccc.idea_id = 1 or null) AS ccount 
FROM op_comments ccc
GROUP BY idea_id
) AS cc ON cid = i.idea_id
```

The above counts how many comments are attached to the idea_id and adds it to the main row.

```
LEFT JOIN op_organs o ON i.post_type = o.organs_id
```

The above joins another table to the existing row, which may or may not be blank

```
WHERE idea_geo = 'International';
```

International above is replaced with a variable which could equal: Local, Regional, National or International.

**Issue**: The query fires but comes back empty, but they work if put individually.  Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Here is the full code to help read it:

```
Here is another issue, I think I have placed the code in the wrong place.  Wanting to add another sub SELECT to count how many comments are per idea:

SELECT i.*, o.organ_name, o.organ_logo, vtable.*, cc.ccount
FROM heroku_056eb661631f253.op_ideas i
JOIN
(SELECT v.idea_Id,
    COUNT(v.agree = 1 or null) as agree,
    COUNT(v.disagree = 1 or null) as disagree,
    COUNT(v.obstain = 1 or null) as abstain
FROM op_idea_vote v
GROUP BY v.idea_id
) AS vtable ON vtable.idea_id = i.idea_id
JOIN 
(SELECT ccc.idea_id AS cid, COUNT(ccc.idea_id = 1 or null) AS ccount 
FROM op_comments ccc
GROUP BY idea_id
) AS cc ON cid = i.idea_id
LEFT JOIN op_organs o ON i.post_type = o.organs_id
WHERE idea_geo = 'International';
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT NEW SOLUTION**

Thanks to WayneC and Conrad we have a fully working query.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT i.*, o.organ_name, o.organ_logo, vtable.*
FROM heroku_056eb661631f253.op_ideas i
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT v.idea_Id, cc.*,
    COUNT(v.agree = 1 or null) as agree,
    COUNT(v.disagree = 1 or null) as disagree,
    COUNT(v.obstain = 1 or null) as abstain
FROM op_idea_vote v 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT idea_id AS id,COUNT(*) AS ccount 
    FROM op_comments cco
    GROUP BY cco.idea_id
    ) AS cc ON cc.id = v.idea_id
GROUP BY v.idea_id
) AS vtable ON vtable.idea_id = i.idea_id
LEFT JOIN op_organs o ON i.post_type = o.organs_id
WHERE idea_geo = 'International';
```

Comment: Which table is idea_geo in? If its in op_organs then you'll need to change your where to `idea_geo = 'International' or idea_geo IS NULL`

Comment: @ConradFrix Hiya.  Its in the table `op_ideas i`

Comment: hmm are you sure that there are any values of Idea_id that are in both subqueries

Comment: Yea, if i take out the second sub, it works like a charm.  And if I put the second sub on it's own, it seemed to work fine.  But I will try again once lil one is in bed.  But I am sure it worked.  It's just knowing where to put the second.  I tried and put it within the first Sub, as logically (to me) that is where it ought to cascade.  No errors, just no results.

Comment: If I were you I would change the two joins to LEFT JOINs and change the select to `SELECT i.idea_id, vtable.idea_id , cc.cid` and confirm that there are records were the second two are not null

Comment: Just to understand this. Are you saying the syntax I have above it correct and it ought to work?  If I take out the second subquery it works like a charm and gives me what I want.  I just want to add another sub to get info from one other table.  The second sub would be easier but for duplicate names, other wise it's just a simple `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM op_comments WHERE idea_id = Variable` But if the sytax is correct, the maybe it's in the wrong order. All tables, other than op_ideas, has the potential to be empty. With a new post for example, so votes or comments.  So is the syntax correct?

Comment: I have updated your code as suggested, but I am getting the results of one row in all thats listed?   Please see above.

Comment: Since your have `SELECT COUNT(*)` in cc your join ON idea_id = v.idea_id` makes no sense. It might has well have been if 1=1. Change that select to `SELECT idea_id, count(*)` and the JOIN to on **cc**.idea_id = v.idea_id

Comment: Perfect.  Updated the code above to the final version.

Comment: I'm gald you found your solution, but you should consider adding your it in as an answer and accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is as follows:

```
SELECT i.*, o.organ_name, o.organ_logo, vtable.*
FROM heroku_056eb661631f253.op_ideas i
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT v.idea_Id, cc.*,
    COUNT(v.agree = 1 or null) as agree,
    COUNT(v.disagree = 1 or null) as disagree,
    COUNT(v.obstain = 1 or null) as abstain
    FROM op_idea_vote v 
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT idea_id AS id,COUNT(*) AS ccount 
    FROM op_comments cco
    GROUP BY cco.idea_id
    ) AS cc ON cc.id = v.idea_id
  GROUP BY v.idea_id
  ) AS vtable ON vtable.idea_id = i.idea_id
  LEFT JOIN op_organs o ON i.post_type = o.organs_id
WHERE idea_geo = 'International';
```